# OR Visible condition showing twice LinkButton Inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asplinkbutton

I am calling java script in above LinkButtons and all LinkButtons are inside into gridview base on question serial number doing visibility of LinkButtons. My above LinkButton4 is not working properly and `OR` condition is not working properly. When I am on serial number 1 or 5 or 10 then showing twice buttons. I think linkbutton4 is not vi-sibling false in serial number 1 or 5 or 10.

Below LinkButtons using inside GridView.

```
   <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn savennext btn-large skip" ID="LinkButton_SAVE_NEXT"
    OnClick="LinkButton_SAVE_NEXT_Click" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() == "1"%>' OnClientClick="return takepic();">SAVE & NEXT</asp:LinkButton>

   <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn savennext btn-large skip" ID="LinkButton1"
   OnClick="LinkButton_SAVE_NEXT_Click" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() == "5"%>' OnClientClick="return takepic1();">SAVE & NEXT</asp:LinkButton>

   <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn savennext btn-large skip" ID="LinkButton3"
   OnClick="LinkButton_SAVE_NEXT_Click" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() == "10"%>' OnClientClick="return takepic2();">SAVE & NEXT</asp:LinkButton>

   <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn savennext btn-large skip" ID="LinkButton4"
   OnClick="LinkButton_SAVE_NEXT_Click" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "1" || Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "5" || Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "10"%>'>SAVE & NEXT</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: i think it should be `AND` not `OR` as i understand.

Comment: I have to write Visible='<%# Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "1" AND Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "5" AND Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "10"%>' .@Badiparmagi

Comment: Update your answer and I will mark as answer,  as you said above that is correct. @Badiparmagi

Comment: I update your answer and Also you can vote my question, If you like my question. @Badiparmagi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button visibility desing should be **AND** otherwise it always returns true.

Check this:

```
   <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn savennext btn-large skip" ID="LinkButton4"
   OnClick="LinkButton_SAVE_NEXT_Click" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "1" && Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "5" && Eval("QuestionSNo").ToString() != "10"%>'>SAVE & NEXT</asp:LinkButton>
```